# how to solve error when downloading images using vba?

Tags: vba, image, download

I tried to download the image from the URL and it worked normally.
but if it is run on a 64 bit computer then an error message
"Compile error in hidden module: Module 10.
This error commonly occurs when code is incompatible with the version,platform"

I don't know what to do, any ideas?

this is my code

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
  Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
  ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
  ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
Dim Ret As Long

Sub Download()
   
    
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sData As Worksheet: Set sData = Sheets("Sheet17")
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 
    FolderName = "C:\Try"
 
    With sData
    For i = 1 To 100
        For x = 5 To 12
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            If Sheet17.Cells(i, x).Value <> "" Then
                strPath = FolderName & "\" & i & "-" & x - 4 & ".jpg"
                Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, Sheet17.Cells(i, x).Value, strPath, 0, 0)
            End If
        Next x
    Next i
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to declare `PtrSafe` for `URLDownloadToFile` for 64 bits and some variables has to be in `LongPtr` instead of `Long`. `Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As Long`

Comment: Hai @RaymondWu thank you